# tf.Variable assign method breaks the tf.GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

When I use the assign method of tf.Variable to change the value of a variable, it brakes the tf.Gradient, e. g., see the code for a toy example below:

(NOTE: I am interested in TensorFlow 2 only.)

```
x = tf.Variable([[2.0,3.0,4.0], [1.,10.,100.]])
patch = tf.Variable([[0., 1.], [2., 3.]])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(patch)
    x[:2,:2].assign(patch)
    y = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(x), axes=1)
    o = tf.reduce_mean(y)
do_dpatch = g.gradient(o, patch)
```

Then it gives me `None` for the `do_dpatch`.

Note that if I do the following it works perfectly fine:

```
x = tf.Variable([[2.0,3.0,4.0], [1.,10.,100.]])
patch = tf.Variable([[0., 1.], [2., 3.]])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(patch)
    x[:2,:2].assign(patch)
    y = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(x), axes=1)
    o = tf.reduce_mean(y)
do_dx = g.gradient(o, x)
```

and gives me:

```
>>>do_dx 
<tf.Tensor: id=106, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 1.,  2., 52.],
       [ 1.,  2., 52.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17735) (see the quote below from alextp) `tf.assign` does not support gradient.

"There is no plan to add a gradient to tf.assign because it's not possible in general to connect the uses of the assigned variable with the graph which assigned it."

So, the above problem can be resolved by the following code:

```
x= tf.Variable([[0.0,0.0,4.0], [0.,0.,100.]])
patch = tf.Variable([[0., 1.], [2., 3.]])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(patch)
    padding = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1]])
    padde_patch = tf.pad(patch, padding, mode='CONSTANT', constant_values=0)
    revised_x = x+ padde_patch
    y = tf.tensordot(revised_x, tf.transpose(revised_x), axes=1)
    o = tf.reduce_mean(y)
do_dpatch = g.gradient(o, patch)
```

which results in

```
do_dpatch

<tf.Tensor: id=65, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 2.],
       [1., 2.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior does make sense. Let's take your first example

```
x = tf.Variable([[2.0,3.0,4.0], [1.,10.,100.]])
patch = tf.Variable([[1., 1.], [1., 1.]])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(patch)
    x[:2,:2].assign(patch)
    y = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(x), axes=1)
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, patch)
```

You are computing dy/d(patch). But your `y` depends on `x` only not on `patch`. Yes, you do assign values to `x` from `patch`. But this operation doesn't carry a reference to the `patch` Variable. It just copies the values.

In short, you are trying to get a gradient w.r.t something it doesn't depend on. So you will get `None`.

Let's look at the second example and why it works.

```
x = tf.Variable([[2.0,3.0,4.0], [1.,10.,100.]])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(x)
    x[:2,:2].assign([[1., 1.], [1., 1.]])
  y = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(x), axes=1)
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
```

This example is perfectly fine. Y depends on x and you are computing `dy/dx`. So you'd get actual gradients in this example.